# Is here the right place to talk about writing/storytelling tropes?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

I've seen a lot of questions about tropes or general storytelling trends, like if not having a happy ending or making the villain change sides is acceptable.

I'm not writing currently, but I have a bunch of questions in the same vein about other people's work.

Is this kind of questions welcome here? (in the not-meta website I mean) Such as "I see a lot of works relying on this trope, is it better to avoid relying on it too much?"

If not, is there a better place on stack exchange for that? My first question would be about something I've observed in a manga, but it would feel weird to ask it in "anime and manga" because it's more related to storytelling than to anything else, the work could be a book, a comic or a movie, the question would be the same.

Answer (score 3):

If the question is one that a writer might ask, it doesn't matter whether or not you write yourself. As long as you want to understand the writing process, that's fine.

If your question is about understanding literature, and not how it is created, then your question might be a better fit for Literature.SE.